# How to Show/Hide Content From Specific Country

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geolocation, blogger

Is there any to show content only in pakistan. I have an ad banner of a pakistani Company and i want to show that banner only in pakistan.

Comment: http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing

Answer (score 4):

You can use a service called [Geo-IP API](http://smart-ip.net/geoip-api) from `smart-ip.net`:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?', function(data) {
        if (data.countryCode == 'PK') {
            $('#ad_banner').show();
            $('body').text('You are from Pakistan');
        }else{
            $('#ad_banner').hide();
            $('body').text('You are from ' + data.countryName);
        }
    });
});
```

where `PK` is the 2-character country identifier of the **[ISO 3166-1 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1)**

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P8j6n/)**